# How is this boorkmarklet working

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

```
javascript:
void((function(d)
{

  if(self!=top||d.getElementById('toolbar')&&d.getElementById('toolbar').getAttribute('data-resizer'))
      return%20false;
      d.write('<!DOCTYPE%20HTML><html%20style="opacity:0;">
               <head>
                   <meta%20charset="utf-8"/>
               </head>

               <body>
                   <a%20data-viewport="320x480"%20data-icon="mobile">Mobile%20(e.g.%20Apple%20iPhone)</a>
                   <a%20data-viewport="320x568"%20data-icon="mobile"%20data-version="5">Apple%20iPhone%205</a>
                   <a%20data-viewport="600x800"%20data-icon="small-tablet">Small%20Tablet</a>
                   <a%20data-viewport="768x1024"%20data-icon="tablet">Tablet%20(e.g.%20Apple%20iPad%202-3rd,%20mini)</a>
                   <a%20data-viewport="1280x800"%20data-icon="notebook">Widescreen</a>

                   <script%20src="http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/resizer.min.js"></script>
               </body>
             </html>')})(document));
```

---

I am trying to put is into  a href="", but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's make it more easily readable by removing the `javascript:void()` and giving new lines

```
(function (d) {
    if (
        self != top ||
        d.getElementById('toolbar') && d.getElementById('toolbar').getAttribute('data-resizer')
        ) return false;
    d.write('<!DOCTYPE HTML><html style="opacity:0;"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/></head><body><a data-viewport="320x480" data-icon="mobile">Mobile (e.g. Apple iPhone)</a><a data-viewport="320x568" data-icon="mobile" data-version="5">Apple iPhone 5</a><a data-viewport="600x800" data-icon="small-tablet">Small Tablet</a><a data-viewport="768x1024" data-icon="tablet">Tablet (e.g. Apple iPad 2-3rd, mini)</a><a data-viewport="1280x800" data-icon="notebook">Widescreen</a><script src="http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/resizer.min.js"></script></body></html>')
})(document);
```

Remember `self === window`. Now, how is it working?
It is saying do nothing if

- it is the not top-most frame or
- there exists an element *#toolbar* with attribute *data-resizer*

else set the document to the code there, which is a few `<a>`s and then imports *http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/resizer.min.js*.

How to make this into a href?
You need to `encodeURI` on it first

```
<a href="javascript:void%20(function%20(d)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self%20!=%20top%20%7C%7C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d.getElementById('toolbar')%20&&%20d.getElementById('toolbar').getAttribute('data-resizer')%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%20return%20false;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d.write('%3C!DOCTYPE%20HTML%3E%3Chtml%20style=%22opacity:0;%22%3E%3Chead%3E%3Cmeta%20charset=%22utf-8%22/%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Ca%20data-viewport=%22320x480%22%20data-icon=%22mobile%22%3EMobile%20(e.g.%20Apple%20iPhone)%3C/a%3E%3Ca%20data-viewport=%22320x568%22%20data-icon=%22mobile%22%20data-version=%225%22%3EApple%20iPhone%205%3C/a%3E%3Ca%20data-viewport=%22600x800%22%20data-icon=%22small-tablet%22%3ESmall%20Tablet%3C/a%3E%3Ca%20data-viewport=%22768x1024%22%20data-icon=%22tablet%22%3ETablet%20(e.g.%20Apple%20iPad%202-3rd,%20mini)%3C/a%3E%3Ca%20data-viewport=%221280x800%22%20data-icon=%22notebook%22%3EWidescreen%3C/a%3E%3Cscript%20src=%22http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/resizer.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E')%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)(document);">Bookmarklet</a>
```

Comment: please say, and how can I call this function without a href, sorry for stupid question :)  I am very new in this

Comment: To call without `<a href>` paste the href's value directly into the URL bar or paste the un-encoded function (it invokes itself) into your browser's developer console ([chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview), [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) (or [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)), [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx)) which can usually be accessed by pressing F12.

Comment: Or, to convert it back into a bookmarklet, depending on your browser, right click it and save bookmark, or drag to bookmarks bar then organise where you want it, etc.